# How can I import a shared groovy script into a pipeline from the same Git repo?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have the following two pipelines in my repository

```kotlin
@Field String ANDROID_EMULATOR = "android-emulator"

pipeline {
    agent { label "android-emulator" }
    stages {
        stage("build") {
            steps {
                gradlew (":build")
            }
        }
    }
}

void gradlew(String tasks) {
    sh "./gradlew $tasks --profile"
}
```

```kotlin
@Field String ANDROID_EMULATOR = "android-emulator"

pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage("PR checks") {
            parallel {
                stage("build 1") {
                    agent { label ANDROID_EMULATOR }
                    steps {
                        gradlew(":one:build")
                    }
                }
                stage("build 2") {
                    agent { label ANDROID_EMULATOR }
                    steps {
                        gradlew(":two:build")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void gradlew(String tasks) {
    sh "./gradlew $tasks --profile"
}
```

As you can see, there is some code duplication between the two - `ANDROID_EMULATOR` and `void gradlew(..)`.

I would like to move them into their own `shared.groovy` file:

```kotlin
@Field String ANDROID_EMULATOR = "android-emulator"

void gradlew(String tasks) {
    sh "./gradlew $tasks --profile"
}
```

And be able to import it into my other pipelines with a single line of code. Gradle allows this to be done with `apply('shared.groovy')`.

Jenkins seems to allow only shared libraries (which are global), and load statements (which need to be loaded as a part of a node, which does not scale well). Does Jenkins lack support for this basic style of code sharing here?

Comment: Shared libraries are only global if globally loaded. They can also be loaded per pipeline: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#using-libraries

Comment: Thanks @MattSchuchard. Is it possible to load a shared library *from* a declarative jenkinsfile pipeline, without configuring it in jenkins manually? I want my shared library to come from the same git repo my pipelines are contained in

Comment: Yes check the section titled "Dynamic Retrieval". Note that method will subvert the script security plugin as a side effect though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the pipeline `load` which is more simple than using shared library, especially when you hope the `shared.groovy` in the same repo as your Jenkinsfiles.

```
// shared.groovy

def gradlew(String tasks) {
    sh "./gradlew $tasks --profile"
}

return this // the return this must be have
```

```
// pipeline 1

pipeline {
    agent { label "android-emulator" }
    stages {
        stage("build") {
            steps {
                scripts {
                     shared = load 'shared.groovy'
                     shared.gradlew (":build")
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
// pipeline 2

pipeline {
    agent { label "android-emulator" }
    stages {
        stage("build") {
            steps {
                scripts {
                     shared = load 'shared.groovy'
                     shared.gradlew ("one:build")
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins shared libraries have a well defined folder structure https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#directory-structure

You can try:

- to implement this folder structure in a subfolder in your repo
- to use a `Dynamic Retrieval` with a scm config that will check out the specific folder

I afraid it is too complicated and even not possible

I think the best approach is to create global shared libraries repo and to implement a `gradleBuild` [custom step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-custom-steps) . In that case your code will be like

Pipeline 1:

```
@Library('somelib')
@Field String ANDROID_EMULATOR = "android-emulator"

pipeline {
   agent { label "android-emulator" }
   stages {
     stage("build") {
        steps {
            gradleBuild ":build"
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Pipeline 2:

```
@Library('somelib')
@Field String ANDROID_EMULATOR = "android-emulator"

pipeline {
  agent none
  stages {
     stage("PR checks") {
        parallel {
            stage("build 1") {
                agent { label ANDROID_EMULATOR }
                steps {
                    gradlew(":one:build")
                }
            }
            stage("build 2") {
                agent { label ANDROID_EMULATOR }
                steps {
                    gradlew(":two:build")
                }
            }
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Shared libraries `vars/gradeBuild.groovy` file:

```
def call(String tasks) {
   sh "./gradlew $tasks --profile"
}
```